# Are not published workshop papers considered in similarity check for an extended journal paper?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, plagiarism, self-plagiarism, workshop

I am going to submit my journal paper in 2 weeks. Besides, there is a workshop whose deadline is in a couple of days. I am going to submit a brief version of my potential journal paper (12 pages) in this workshop (4 pages).

In the workshop website it's mentioned that "Please note the papers will not be published in a proceedings but will be made available via this website."

Now I'm concerned about one thing. As the workshop papers will be made available via this website, I assume they will be considered in the similarity check for my extended journal paper submission.

Will not that cause my journal paper to be considered as plagiarism (or self-plagiarism)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to the question of (self) plagiarism you should cite one work in the other. I would guess that you cite the journal article in the conference submission. You can also cross cite, of course. That avoids the question of plagiarism (and self plagiarism) altogether.

But the other question is whether the journal publisher will consider the work as already published if you present it. If they have strict rules about original work, you might have an issue. The editor of the journal should be able to settle that for you.

Among other things, you can say in the conference submission as a footnote, that an extended version of this has been/will be published in Journal...

Comment: Thanks. What is "cross cite"?

Comment: Each paper cites the other. A bit rare but possible if they are written together.

Comment: Yeah, but actually I may not submit the journal in the time of workshop submission. Is that fine to cite the journal paper in the workshop as "Submitted" (since I'll definitely submit the journal version soon)?

Comment: Whatever is honest: submitted, in preparation, in review, ...

Answer (score 0):

Just water it down for the conference.  Basically do a version of your slides.  Also all they (likely) need now for the meeting is your abstract.  Send that in and figure out paper later.

Answer (score 0):

It could be detected by the softare, and depending on the requirements of the journal and/or the conference you could have the paper rejected by one or both venues.

In most disciplines, journals only accept submissions that are new and not previously published elsewhere in any form with the possible exception of papers based on MS/Ph.D. theses.  Journals that take this stance would typically consider "published on a website" as published.  The conference organizers are warning you that appearing on this website could be considered publication.

In some disciplines, it is more common for journals to allow for extended versions of shorter conference papers to be published later as journal papers.  However, there must be some significant expansion and rewriting of the paper and it is important to disclose the prior publication when you submit such a paper.

If the journal has a "must be original, not previously published" rule and they discover that you've broken that rule, your paper will be rejected and you may be blackballed from any future submission to that journal.

So, check the submission guidelines for both the journal and the conference before submitting your paper.  If the conference doesn't mind and the journal is willing to accept an extended conference paper then you should disclose that you've submitted a shorter version of the paper to the conference when you submit your extended version to the journal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the policies of both the workshop and the journal. If those policies are not clear, then contact the workshop chair and journal editor or include a note with your submission explaining the situation up front.

There is a lot of variation in policies. Some journals won't allow anything like this, whereas others will accept papers that have already been published in conference proceedings. What you are planning is *probably* alright, but you need to check.